# How to spatially join several attributes of one layer to a unique one on a second layer

Tags: pyqgis, spatial-join, mmqgis

My goal is to link all the attributes of an input layer (that has a UTM CRS projection matrix and point coordinates but no geometries) to the geometries of another layer based on the spatial analysis. In particular, I want to join them if they intersect or if the geometry contains the dot equal to the coordinates in the input layer. Using the plugin MMQGIS, I am able to merge the two dataset. The problem is following: often multiple observations lies on the same geometry. MMQGIS only returns a random attribute of the input layer but reports correctly the number of points that intersect the geometry of the second one. I would like to have instead a new layer in which all the input attributes are reported. This means that the geometries' id will be duplicated in those cases with multiple inputs on the same geometry. Is there a way to easily perform this task? Both PyQGIS or icons solutions are useful.

Comment: Have you tried using the **Join attributes by location** tool? This spatially joins each feature of one layer to another and you can specify the option of keeping all attributes. You can find this tool in either _Vector > Data Management Tools_ or the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Yes but the program breaks all the times. From your suggestion however I realize that I have not be 100% clear. MMQGIS reports all the attributes (all the columns), but it assigns only a set of specific values to the line of a geometry that intersects more than one point. Let me clarify this with an example: if my dots are district capitals and my geometries the regions, when I spatially join them I can retrieve the number of district capitals per district, but not the specific ids of each of them. Only one district capital's characteristics are reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution I found: I used a very small buffer (100 meters) around my points coordinates in order to create a geometry. Then I used the command Intersect from the Geo-processing Tools. The saved shape file reports each intersection between the two geometries in a different raw as I wanted.